# Magento 1.9.2.2 Datwflow Import Product Price Update CSV

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv, dataflow

i need to update some prices in the shop and made this many times in the last years. But now i have the problem that magento kills my product descriptions on update.

My CSV file has only two fields. SKU and price.

My Dateflow Profile is this:

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">     <var name="type">file</var>     <var name="path">var/import</var>     <var name="filename"><![CDATA[Hensel.csv]]></var>     <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var> </action>  <action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">     <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[;]]></var>     <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>     <var name="fieldnames"></var>     <var name="map">         <map name="SKU"><![CDATA[sku]]></map>         <map name="price"><![CDATA[price]]></map>     </var>     <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>     <var name="number_of_records">1</var>     <var name="decimal_separator"><![CDATA[,]]></var>     <var name="adapter">catalog/convert_adapter_product</var>     <var name="method">parse</var> </action>
```

Any ideas, whats going wrong with the importer? I'm pretty sure, that this works many times ... the last usage was 2016.